# How to prevent fgets blocks when file stream has no new data

Tags: c, popen, fgets

I have a `popen()` function which executes `tail -f sometextfile`. Aslong as there is data in the filestream obviously I can get the data through `fgets()`. Now, if no new data comes from tail, `fgets()` hangs. I tried `ferror()` and `feof()` to no avail. How can I make sure `fgets()` doesn't try to read data when nothing new is in the file stream?

One of the suggestion was `select()`. Since this is for Windows Platform select doesn't seem to work as anonymous pipes do not seem to work for it (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152807/what-is-wrong-with-this-popen-select-example)).

Answer (score 32):

In Linux (or any Unix-y OS), you can mark the underlying file descriptor used by popen() to be non-blocking.

```
#include <fcntl.h>

FILE *proc = popen("tail -f /tmp/test.txt", "r");
int fd = fileno(proc);

int flags;
flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags);
```

If there is no input available, fgets will return NULL with errno set to EWOULDBLOCK.

Answer (score 15):

`fgets()` is a blocking read, it is supposed to wait until data is available if there is no data.

You'll want to perform asynchronous I/O using `select()`, `poll()`, or `epoll()`. And then perform a read from the file descriptor when there is data available.

These functions use the file descriptor of the `FILE*` handle, retrieved by: `int fd = fileno(f);`

Comment: Definitely use select() - if you have a FILE * and you need a file descriptor, use fileno().  If you have a file descriptor and you need a FILE *, use fdopen().

Comment: Unfortunately, I think select() doesn't work on pipes under Windows.

Comment: Mixing select() and fgets() is dangerous. A FILE* contains internal buffers that select() isn't aware of. The correct answer is O_NONBLOCK.

Answer (score 0):

I you would use POSIX functions for IO instead of those of C library, you could use [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) or [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll).

Answer (score 0):

You can instead try reading sometextfile using low-level IO functions (open(), read(), etc.), like tail itself does. When there's nothing more to read, read() returns zero, but will still try to read more the next time, unlike FILE* functions.

Comment: this was just an example. the idea is to pull data and pass it through a mutex object to a flash instance.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problems by using threads , specifically [`_beginthread` , `_beginthreadex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/beginthread-beginthreadex).

Comment: If you answered your own question, please set this as the answer and possibly post your solution.