# How to search a character in a stream and push back in stream using pipes

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I want to search a character in stream and push back in stream without consuming any data.
I am using fgetc but program is stuck on callling fgetc.

below is my test program.

```
int main(void)
{
  int     fd[2], nbytes;
  pid_t   childpid;
  char    string[] = "Hello, world!\n";
  char    readbuffer[80];

  pipe(fd);

  if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
    {
      perror("fork");
      exit(1);
    }

  if(childpid == 0)
    {
      /* Child process closes up input side of pipe */
      close(fd[0]);

      /* Send "string" through the output side of pipe */
      write(fd[1], string, (strlen(string)+1));
      exit(0);
    }
  else
    {
      /* Parent process closes up output side of pipe */
      close(fd[1]);
      int dummy;
      fd_set set;
      struct timeval timeout;
      FD_ZERO (&set);
      FD_SET (fd[0], &set);
      timeout.tv_sec = 1;
      timeout.tv_usec = 0;
      if (select (fd[0]+1, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout))
        {
          dummy = fgetc (stdin);
          ungetc (dummy, stdin);
          // Search for character
          if (dummy == 0x03)
               // Todo  
        }
    }

  return(0);
}
```

So, what is wrong with code why program stuck on fgetc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to `fgetc` from `stdin` (which is your terminal), not the pipe. You're not using the pipe anywhere. Try to understand what your code is actually doing.

I think you intended to `dup2` the pipe fd to 0, the stdin fd. There are thousands of examples of this.

Without Libc's buffering, or implementing it youself, you can't do what you ask - once a byte is read from the pipe, it's yours and gone from the pipe.

Comment: thanks for point out that I'm using terminal input from stdin not pipes that save my lot of time.

Comment: are you saying that the function: `ungetc()`  will not push back a character on a pipe?

Comment: No, I'm saying [`ungetc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ungetc) is a libc function, which works on `FILE*` streams - a libc abstraction on top of the *actual* file descriptors (like your pipes).

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two issues. The one is that once a byte is consumed from the stream, you cannot push it back. Second, `fgetc` is a blocking function such that it will wait until data is available, and you cannot tell `fgetc` to return if not (or even to return once a timeout has been reached).

For the first issue, you could wrap the relevant stream by a buffer, which has then to be used throughout your program and where prefetching would work.

For the second issue, see, for example, this (or similar) posts on [non blocking I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/a/149988/2630032) (please don't forget to upvote the referenced answer if helpful).